# esearch in reutils package: how to specify dataset?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a question about the [reutils package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reutils/reutils.pdf). There is a function called `esearch()` which allows you to search the GEO database. So, I entered the same query that I would use in GEO:

```
UIDs <- esearch( term = "METHYLATION PROFILING BY ARRAY[DATASET TYPE]")
```

but `esearch()` doesn't recognize `DATASET TYPE`.

How do I specify the dataset type to `esearch()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to specify the database. For GEO, that would be "gds". `einfo()` gives a vector of database names.

```
UIDs <- esearch(term = "METHYLATION PROFILING BY ARRAY[DATASET TYPE]", db = "gds")
```